# File created in image by docker not reflecting in container run by docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker file which has a command `RUN python3 manage.py dumpdata --natural-foreign --exclude=auth.permission --exclude=contenttypes     --indent=4 > data.json"` this creates a Json file.

when i build the docker file it creates an image of specific name and when i run that using below command and open in bash i am able to see the data.json file created.

`docker run -it --rm vijeth11/fassionplaza bash`

[files in Docker container created via above cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Esj5T.png)

when i use the same image and run `docker compose run web bash` cmd
i am not able to see the data.json file, while other files are present in the container.

[files in Docker container created via Docker compose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtIt9.png)

Is there anything wrong in my docker commands

Command used to build:

```
docker build --no-cache -t vijeth11/fassionplaza .
```

Docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3" 
services: 
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=fashionplaza
    ports: 
      - "5432:5432"
 
  web:    
    image: vijeth11/fassionplaza
    command: >
      sh -c "ls -l && python3 manage.py makemigrations && python3 manage.py migrate && python3 manage.py loaddata data.json && gunicorn --bind :8000 --workers 3 FashionPlaza.wsgi"
    volumes: 
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"     
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /code
COPY ./Backend /code/Backend
COPY ./frontEnd /code/frontEnd
WORKDIR /code/Backend
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
WORKDIR /code/Backend/FashionPlaza
RUN python3 manage.py dumpdata --natural-foreign \
   --exclude=auth.permission --exclude=contenttypes \
   --indent=4 > data.json
RUN chmod 755 data.json
WORKDIR /code/frontEnd/FashionPlaza
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt -y install curl dirmngr apt-transport-https lsb-release ca-certificates 
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash
RUN apt install nodejs -y
RUN npm i
RUN npm run prod
ARG buildtime_variable=PROD
ENV server_type=$buildtime_variable
WORKDIR /code/Backend/FashionPlaza
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You map your current directory to `/code` when you run with these lines in your docker-compose file

```
volumes: 
  - .:/code
```

That hides all existing files in /code and replaces it with the mapped directory.

Since your data.json file is located in /code/Backend/FashionPlaza in the image, it becomes hidden and inaccessible.

The best thing to do is to map your volumes to empty directories in the image, so you don't inadvertently hide anything.

Comment: Thank you this helped me very much and I came across the same thing in docker compose documents in below link

https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/#step-5-edit-the-compose-file-to-add-a-bind-mount